# Telnet Automation with Expect: Slow authentication?

Tags: authentication, tcl, telnet, expect

I'm sending a command to a Mikrotik router using Telnet.

```
telnet 192.168.100.100 -l admin
Password: pass1234
[admin@ZYMMA] > /interface pppoe-server remove [find user=aspeed13]
[admin@ZYMMA] > quit
```

It works fine.

Now I want to automate it using expect tcl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
spawn telnet 192.168.100.100
expect "Login:"
send "admin\r"
expect "Password:"
send "pass1234\r"
expect "\[admin@ZYMMA\] >"
send "/interface pppoe-server remove \[find user=aspeed13\]\r"
expect "\[admin@ZYMMA\] >"
send "quit\r"
```

It works, but after authentication (line 6: `send "pass1234\r"`) when the Router CLI is loading it freezes for ~10seconds with the following characters `^[[?6c^[[24;3R`
Then the scripts runs ok.

My question is why Telnet loads fast when accessed manually and it takes too much time when accessed via expect script? I read in forums about telnet automation they say telnet is slow, but since manually it's too fast why it takes time to load with expect?

Comment: `expect` is `tcl`, not `bash`

Comment: Does it work if you substitute the next `expect` line with `expect -re ">"` ?

Comment: thanks ninjalj for the correction.

Comment: concerning substituting the next line with expect -re ">"

I tried it but the script stopped and it waited until timeout. any other suggestions?

Comment: add `exp_internal 1` to the top of your script to see how expect is trying to match

Answer (score 3):

What you're seeing is blow-back from terminal negotiation, which is because you're not running in a *real* terminal. (Strictly, you are – that's expect's magic – but it's not behaving as a normal terminal does.)

The easiest fix is to set the terminal to something else before spawning the `telnet` session, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
set env(TERM) dumb
spawn telnet 192.168.100.100
# Rest of your script goes here ...
```

Alternatively, you could try to respond correctly to the request to enter VT102 mode and the report of the cursor location (which feels like a lot of work) or you could rewrite your code so that it does everything inside `interact` (which connects the other end with the real terminal that you're running inside). But if setting an environment variable fixes it, why go to all that extra hassle?

(NB: I suggest setting the terminal to `dumb` here, but the key is that you want the stupidest terminal that works. Dumb terminals are ideal, because they're just about *totally* stupid, making it easy to pretend to be them…)

Comment: I tried `set env(TERM) dumb` without success, still connection delay is the same :(

Comment: Do u think using ssh could be faster than telnet or it's just the same. For example could it be possible to:
open/send command/close in less than 3 seconds using telnet (or ssh?)

Comment: @Naim: I'd guess it to be about the same in my experience, enough that there's no reason to run insecure. (I like being able to use cryptokeys for auth, which actually makes it faster in practice for me.)

Comment: Thank you @Donal: You're definitely right concerning the security issue. The reason why I'm stressing on low response time is because this script is to be called by a php webpage. I tried phpTelnet but it takes almost the same time(a little more). So actually I gained only a few seconds by shifting to expect script. I tried perl script with its Net::Telnet class and I gained some more seconds, the whole process takes 10sec. So as it seems there's no possible terminal connection via script below the 10s threshold. Do u agree, or I'm wrong?

Comment: with ssh, you can also pass the command and the arguments that you want to execute as parameter for ssh. With cryptokeys and sshagent or only a key without password can be much easier: just execute `ssh admin@192.168.100.100 /bin/bash -c "/interface pppoe-server remove [find user=aspeed13]"` - assuming that the remote shell is bash. (this way you don't have the delay for send somthing, wait for response, send...)

Comment: is it "real" telnet however?  I suppose it depends how you define real..

Answer (score 2):

My answer is possibly too late. This is "Telnet autoconfig command"...I was this problem and found at Mikrotik Wiki this solution:

Add +t after login name. This switch autodetect to off.

Example:
send "admin+t\r"

It is works great and not "wait cca 10 sec" after login by expect.

There is link to Mikrotik WiKi help with more "switches":
[http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Console_login_process#FAQ](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual%3aConsole_login_process#FAQ)

P.S.: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with netcat, with telnet emulation enabled?

Comment: Do u think netcat can be more useful than expect? i'll read abt it, but if you can provide me a small sample i'd be thankful

Comment: to my understanding, expect and interact are the way to go.  I don't know that netcat has scripting capability..

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late to answer.
But if you want to speed up your character input with expect.
Try to generate the script with "autoexpect" command, which will save the
interaction in a file named "script.exp" in the same directory from where
you ran the command.

For instance:
cd $HOME
autoexpect telnet 192.168.100.100
 # some more telnet commands here
exit

All the above commands will be saved in ~/script.exp
About Tcl, I don't know if ths script can be ran via tcl.